# VMWare tools config fails after upgrade to VMPlayer 6.0.1 on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-tools

after upgrading my VMWare player to v.6.0.1, the VMWare tools installation on the guest Ubuntu 13.04 OS fails.
Compilation of modules goes fine, but then the vmware config part fails when starting the services, with the following output.

```
Creating a new initrd boot image for the kernel.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
vmware-tools-thinprint start/running
initctl: Job failed to start
Unable to start services for VMware Tools

Execution aborted.
```

VMWare tools version is 9.6.1-1378637.
Updating to Ubuntu 13.10 didn't help. I also tried disabling the thin-print service (i.e., saying "no" rather than the default answer), which could seem to be the issue from the output, and other options which are normally enabled by default (like file drag and drop), but that didn't help either.
Any idea on how I could troubleshoot this further?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I resolved the problem by:

1. uninstalling vmware-tools with `sudo vmware-uninstall-tools.pl`,
2. removing vmware-tools related directories/files in **/etc**, **/usr/lib**, **/usr/sbin**,
3. installing vmware-tools from scratch with executing `sudo ./vmware-install.pl -d` (extract installation files from archive located on mounted virtual-CD previous to this; `VM -> Install VMware Tools` in menubar to mount CD).

Comment: thanks, through this approach helped I solved the problem permanently!

Comment: +1 Worked for me. Directories I specifically removed was `/etc/vmware-tools`, `/usr/lib/vmware-tools`.